# Do we represent software in network physical diagram?

Tags: network, network-access, network-discovery

I am working on creating a wireless infrastructure for a production site and as I am creating a physical network diagram representing the structure of devices, subnets etc. in the network diagram.

So just wanted to ask that do we represent cloud services since it is software in the network diagram as well? if yes then how?

Based on my understanding we only represent physical devices in the network diagram.

I will really appreciate help towards this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explained that you're creating a *physical network diagram* and that often means the location of devices and the cables interconnecting them.  Any other use of *physical network diagram* is going to be confusing.

You'll want more than one diagram to help you plan and communicate your design to other stakeholders.  A diagram of rack/room/conduit locations is great for understanding things like possible wireless coverage or intended cable paths.  It's not the best way to visualize the network topology or how applications and users are connected to the network.

If you search Google Images for *network topology diagram* it should give you some inspiration.

Create several diagrams.  Cloud applications don't belong on your *physical network diagram.*

Comment: You mentioned that Cloud applications don't belong to a physical network diagram. Can you explain why? Just wanted to know, please. Also upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me

Comment: You need to create separate diagrams for the *physical* network topology (cabling and cable plants, closets, ...), and for the *logical* network (routes, locations and interconnects, possibly services). For complex services you should consider additional diagrams.

Comment: @Zac67 But with physical network, cloud services cannot be part of it?

Comment: A cloud service is a logical construct, so not a part of a physical diagram - that stops at the WAN port.

Comment: @Zac67 If I have to support 200-300 devices(tablets, Laptop ) then how many access points I would require?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow That's an entire different question that's been asked before, just search. Essentially, you need to have a wireless survey done as there's no simple answer (depends on building layout and materials, geographical spread, workloads, ...). You might get away with as few as 10 but might require more than 100 WAPs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113724/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-zac67).